# Vb.net - Split String and convert to DateTime

Tags: vb.net, datetime, datagridview, split

I have 1 datagridview named IncomingMailDGV.

Sample data on Contents Column:

R-1 temperature (6.25) rose above high bound SLTCR at Warehouse-1 at  27/07/15 13:40
R-2 temperature (6.62) rose above high bound SLTCR at Store at 27/07/15 13:42
R-3 temperature (6.31) rose above high bound SLTCR at Warehouse-2 at 27/07/15 13:45

Note: Some contents has three spaces on the last part of the message.

I want to get the date and time which is placed on the last part and convert it to this format: "M/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt"

I'm using below code but its not working:

```
 Sub FilterAlert()
      Try

        Dim Dbcon As New OleDbConnection(connStr)

        Dbcon.Open()

        For x As Integer = 0 To IncomingMailDGV.Rows.Count - 1

            Dim line2 As String = IncomingMailDGV.Rows(x).Cells("Contents").Value.ToString
            Dim separators() As String = {",", " ", "(", ")"}
            Dim length As Integer = line2.Length
            Dim alertdatetime As String
            Dim alertdate_time As String


            data2 = line2.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            alertdate_time = line2.Substring(length - 14, 14)

            Dim alertstring = alertdate_time.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

            alertdatetime = alertstring(0)

            alertdatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(alertdatetime, "dd/MM/yyHH:mm", Nothing)

    console.writeline (alertdatetime)
        Next

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)

    End Try

End Sub
```

Update: Some cells on Contents Column are empty.

Comment: Not working meaning what?  You're code is throwing an exception? Not getting the correct data?  I mean if I had to guess, your ParseExact doesn't look right to me.  You're using the format"dd/MM/yyHH:mm" and the sample data look likes your format should be "dd/MM/yy HH:mm" (Note the space between year and hour).

Comment: turn on Option Strict - that wont compile. `Dim alertdatetime As String` says it is a string, but this: `alertdatetime = DateTime.ParseExact(...)` returns a DateTime type.  Dates do not have formats; formats are for how we display Data data to users

Comment: Error is string was not recognized as a valid datetime.

Comment: debug it to make sure you are getting the datetime data and only the datetime data into the string; then make sure your format string precisely matches the format of the date data and get the date into a proper DateTime variable.

Comment: I change alertdatetime to DateTime instead of String. But still string was not recognized as a valid datetime.

Comment: instead of trying to put the incoming text into one single format to parse from (which may be where your approach fails), use the overload: `TryParseExact Method (String, String(), IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)` and pass the formats it can be in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean that there may be more than one space between the date and the time, then you can just take the last 14 characters from the string. The following code assumes that the date and time are always preceded by " at ". It's not clear what you want to do if the string is not in the correct format, this code simply ignores invalid strings.

Note that DateTime doesn't have a format, it's just numbers. You can use `DateTime.ToString` to output the date and time in whatever format you want.

This code is intended to replace everything inside the For loop.

```
Dim line2 As String = IncomingMailDGV.Rows(x).Cells("Contents").Value.ToString
Dim pos As Integer = line2.LastIndexOf(" at ")
If pos < 0 Then Continue For

Dim alertstring() As String = line2.Substring(pos + 4).Split({" "c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
If alertstring.length <> 2 Then Continue For

Dim alertdatetime As DateTime 
If Not DateTime.TryParseExact(alertstring(0) & alertstring(1), "dd/MM/yyHH:mm", _
  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, Nothing, alertdatetime) Then Continue For 

Console.WriteLine(alertdatetime.ToString("M/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt"))
```

Comment: `"dd/MM/yyHH:mm"` is likely part of the problem: the sample data shown is `dd/MM/yy HH:mm` (note the space).

Comment: @Plutonix The OP mentions the possibility of a variable number of spaces (I'm assuming between the date and the time). That explains why he splits the string on (among other things) spaces and removes empty entries. Concatenating the array elements containing the date and the time means that the variable number of spaces between them is replaced by no space at all.

Comment: sorry, missed that part